# Is this class a POJO

Tags: java, pojo, oop

I have a doubt regarding POJO.

Take below example

```
public class User
{
     String user="";
     String password="";
     String firstName="";
     String lastName="";
     ChallengeQuestions challengeQuestions;

     //getter and setters for these prooperties
}

public class ChallengeQuestions
{
    String question="";
    String answer="";

    //getter and setters for these properties
}
```

Here is my question, whether `User` class is a POJO or not.

Thanks,
Narendra

Comment: Does it actually matter in any meaningful way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POJO i.e. Plain Old Java Object refers to all user defined types that do not have to extend a specific/special **prespecified** class or specialized **prespecified** interface.
Your class fits in this category so it is a POJO.

Comment: What counts as prespecified?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. See ['Plain Old Java Object' (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object).

> The term "POJO" is mainly used to
>   denote a Java object which does not
>   follow any of the major Java object
>   models, conventions, or frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

I would have said that a POJO is distinct from a JavaBean.  A POJO does not need to have setters or getters and it would more clearly be a POJO without them.

Your comments suggests you intended to add getters and setters to follow the JavaBean standard and as such this is not a POJO as it is intended to comply with the JavaBean convention.

Comment: It's not *really* JavaBeans as the objects (in the example) aren't serializable (which is a requirement for JavaBean).

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, Good point. I would think private fields are also expected for a JavaBean.  However, writing "getter and setters for these prooperties" like we should know what that means implies it is intended to follow an understood convention.